# Check box tag in rails always checked in nest form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for @show, :html => {:multipart => true, :class=> 'edit_show'} do |f| %>

    <%= render :partial => "/shared/audience_picker", :object => f.object  %>

<% end %>
```

The partial looks like this:

```
<% Audience.all.each do |audience| -%>
    <label>
    <%= check_box_tag "#{object.class.name.underscore}[audience_ids][]", audience.id, :class => 'audience' %><%= audience.name %>
    </label>
    <br/>
<% end -%>
```

This is generating two checkboxes that are always checked, like below:

```
[x] External
[x] Internal
```

How do I uncheck them and when being being edited, have right one already checked?

I've already tried `:checked => true / :checked => false` and it has no effect on the checkboxes.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third argument to [check_box_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) indicates if it should be checked or not

So the following would make it render unchecked

```
<%= check_box_tag "#{object.class.name.underscore}[audience_ids][]", audience.id, false, :class => 'audience' %><%= audience.name %>
```

In edit, pass the value based on your attribute

Comment: amazing! that worked! how would I default select on edit though?

Comment: In your edit view, set the third argument based on the value you are editing